# How to check if a mysql column is not NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

I track if someone is 'an artist' with MySQL. If the user is an artist the artist column goes from NULL to Y, I have this part sorted. However, I cannot work out how to check if the artist column for the user is Y so that I can disable features for that user. The site mainly uses cookies for logins so I need to have the query check for Y where username and password equal the cookie. When artist = Y content should be shown.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username']; 
$pass = $_COOKIE['password']; 
include ("../database.php");

if (mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM members WHERE username='$username' ,
       artist = 'Y'")) {

    //artist specific content goes here
   echo '<div class="bubble"><h1>Artist</h1><div class="innerbubble">Some text</div></div>'; 
}
```

No idea what to do now.

Comment: Have you tried WHERE username='$username' AND artist = 'Y' instead of ','

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE artist IS NULL` or something similar?

Comment: As Jerome pointed out, the query should be `WHERE username='$username' AND artist='Y'`. Another alternative would be `AND artist IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: MySQL accepts queries like `WHERE abc IS NULL` or `WHERE xyz IS NOT NULL` -- does this help?

Comment: Using AND in the WHERE clause should fix at least one issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //artists if
   $username = $_COOKIE['username']; 
   $pass = $_COOKIE['password']; 
   include ("../database.php");
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM members WHERE username='$username' , artist = 'Y'");
   $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

  // check the total count for artist 
      if ($count > 0) {
     //artist specific content goes here

       echo '<div class="bubble"><h1>Artist</h1><div class="innerbubble">Hi there, I see       that yo are an artist so you have access to loads of awesome features. Contact us with ease, upload new tracks, share your street sessions and tell everyone about your latest gigs.</div></div>'; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few recommendations beyond what other answers have suggested.

1) Cookies are great for development, but they are able to be viewed and edited by their owners. I would suggest using sessions; you can still store information regarding a user into them, but it isn't accessible by that user.

2) Prepared statements, prepared statements, prepared statements! If I set my username to

```
'; DELETE FROM members;--
```

your members table would be scrapped! By using a prepared statement, strings passed in to the query are parameterized and not passed in literally.

Guide:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Using prepared statements, your query becomes

```
SELECT artist FROM members WHERE username=? AND artist='Y'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I had considered using sessions but went for cookies as I wanted the user to stay logged in for a longer period of time. I could not see what damage the user could do if edited the cookie so went for them. What do you mean by the username being set as "...DELETE..."? Does that mean the user can simply register with that name and the whole table is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following with your query:

```
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE username='$username' AND artist = 'Y' LIMIT 1");
   if($res){
     $count = mysql_fetch_array($res);
         if($count[0]>0){
       /* Artist content goes here */
         }
    }
```